# How to fix error message in R Studio from for loop?

Tags: r

I have a for loop attempting to generate 1000 datasets of a negative binomial with different n values. However, when I run the loop, it gives me an error message for each vector.

```
x10 <- rep(0,1000)
x25 <- rep(0,1000)
x50 <- rep(0,1000)
x100 <- rep(0,1000)

for (i in 1:1000) {
  x10[i] <- negative_binomial(10, 5, .7)
  x25[i] <- negative_binomial(25, 5, .7)
  x50[i] <- negative_binomial(50, 5, .7)
  x100[i] <- negative_binomial(100, 5, .7)
}
```

The error messages are (over and over and over again):

```
Warning in x10[i] <- negative_binomial(10, 5, 0.7) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Warning in x25[i] <- negative_binomial(25, 5, 0.7) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Warning in x50[i] <- negative_binomial(50, 5, 0.7) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Warning in x100[i] <- negative_binomial(100, 5, 0.7) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

When I print the vectors, the values only go to 981 instead of 1000, so I think that is why I am receiving these errors but I do not know how to correct them.

Also, the function I created for this is:

```
negative_binomial <- function(N, r, p){
  results <- rep(0, N)
  for(i in 1:N){
   success <- 0
   trials <- 0
   while(success < r){
      trial.outcome <- sample(c(0,1), size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))
      success <- success + trial.outcome
      trials <- trials + 1
   }
  results[i] <- trials
  }
  results
}
```

Comment: your function produces a vector the length of the first argument, see length(negative_binomial(25,5,.7)) and length(negative_binomial(100,5,.7)), so you need to account for that in the vectors you want to store the results in.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your solution does resolve the error but now the loop only provides a vector of the n values. For example, x10 is now 1000 values of 10, x25 is now 1000 values of 25, etc.

Comment: my previous comment just showed that the function is producing vectors of different lengths, so the error is telling you that you are trying to store vectors of length 10000, 25,000, 50,000, and 100,000 in a vector of size 10,000. If the function does what you want then you need to provide out vectors of different sizes

Comment: I see but that question is asking for n = 10, 25, 50, 100 - generate 1000 datasets. So, I only want 1000, not 10,000, 25,000, 50,000, 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the function is producing different length outputs, but you give it the same length vector to store the output. If the function does what you want then you need to provide out vectors of different sizes.

One option is to create matrices with the right dimensions to store each iteration as a row.

```
negative_binomial <- function(N, r, p){
  results <- rep(0, N)
  for(i in 1:N){
    success <- 0
    trials <- 0
    while(success < r){
      trial.outcome <- sample(c(0,1), size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))
      success <- success + trial.outcome
      trials <- trials + 1
    }
    results[i] <- trials
  }
  results
}

x10 <-  matrix(nrow = 1e3, ncol = length(negative_binomial(10, 5, .7)))
x25 <-  matrix(nrow = 1e3, ncol = length(negative_binomial(25, 5, .7)))
x50 <-  matrix(nrow = 1e3, ncol = length(negative_binomial(50, 5, .7)))
x100 <-  matrix(nrow = 1e3, ncol = length(negative_binomial(100, 5, .7)))

for (i in 1:1000) {
  x10[i,] <- negative_binomial(10, 5, .7)
  x25[i,] <- negative_binomial(25, 5, .7)
  x50[i,] <- negative_binomial(50, 5, .7)
  x100[i,] <- negative_binomial(100, 5, .7)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued response and help. I understand the error but unfortunately, it seems the solution you provided caused other issues later in my code. I still do not understand why if I am looping 1000 times and my vector is of length 1000 it is producing this error.

Comment: it's because the function produces something the length of its first argument

Answer (score 0):

Create a vector of length 1000 and type "list".  Then use double brackets `[[i]]` to access/change the list entries.

```
x10 <- vector("list", 1000)
x25 <- vector("list", 1000)
x50 <- vector("list", 1000)
x100 <- vector("list", 1000)

for (i in 1:1000) {
    x10[[i]] <- negative_binomial(10, 5, .7)
    x25[[i]] <- negative_binomial(25, 5, .7)
    x50[[i]] <- negative_binomial(50, 5, .7)
    x100[[i]] <- negative_binomial(100, 5, .7)
}
```

Then `x10` is a list of length 1000, each element of the list is a vector of length 10.  You can use a for loop to compute the mean of each one:

```
meanx10 <- vector("numeric", 1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
    meanx10[[i]] <- sum(x10[[i]])/length(x10[[i]])
}
```

When you are computing with the list elements, it can be tricky to work inside the for loop.  When you're developing, use `x10[[1]]` which is the first vector in your list.  Once you can compute what you need with that, paste it inside your for loop and replace the `1` with `i`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, it seems this solution will not work in this context given I use the table function on some of the vectors. The error that is being produced it "Error in table(x10) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with these x10, x25, etc?

Comment: This is the next bit of code, where I am looking to just calculate the mean and variance without the functions. probs <- as.vector(table(x10)/length(x10))
sortedvals <- sort(unique(x10))
meanx10 <- sum(sortedvals*probs)
meanx10
mean(x10)
plot(density(meanx10, bw = .2))

Comment: Okay.  See my updated answer for a hint on how to compute with the list.  Your code will also work, but you must use the double brackets `[[i]]` to access the list elements inside a for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. I appreciate all your time and help!